# Internet not working with "Home" profile in Firewall

Tags: networking, wireless, firewall

Recently my Internet is not working after selecting the "Home" profile in Firewall configuration. If I select "Office" Profile, then Internet works.Is there any issue if I select Office profile on my Home wifi? If not, then I can continue to use this profile.
But still it is very strange because it used to work earlier without any issues. Any advice is helpful.

Comment: What does `sudo ufw status verbose` tell you in  terminal ?

Comment: @Sergiy    here it is: amogh@amogh-HP-Laptop-15q-bu0xx:~$ sudo ufw status verbose  
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

Comment: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing) should be fine for general usecase.

Comment: So it doesn't matter much if profile is set as "Office" instead of "Home" right? Since both have same incoming outgoing rules